# "Horrendous of childhoods" is it grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

The original sentence is:

> People from the most horrendous of childhoods can have good lives.

Why do we need to use "of" here?

Comment: The structure in question is _the [superlative adjective] of [(usually plural) noun]_. It's a very common structure also found in simpler cases like “the biggest of the houses”.

Comment: So, if I say the same but without "of" will it be correct as well?

Comment: @sergey you'd probably say "People from horrendous childhoods can have good lives". It's the superlative adjective "most" that requires the "the" and "of" in this structure.

Comment: But if I use singular noun is it ok: "People from the most horrendous childhood.."?

Comment: @Sergey No. Because "the most horrendous" with the singular "childhood" means there was one and only one most horrendous childhood, and so multiple people can't be "from" it. Only one person - the person with the worst childhood in all of history - can be from that definite singular "most".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Of* is used to refer to a subset of a larger set. It is the 7th case found at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of#Preposition "Having partitive effect."

There is the set of all the childhoods people have ever had, and then there is the subset that were particularly horrendous. Since that subset is part of the larger set, they are "the most horrendous of childhoods".

> Why do we need to use "of" here?

Well, you could leave it out and have something very similar, but not quite the same.

"The most horrendous childhoods" are childhoods that were very horrendous.

"The most horrendous of childhoods" are in the category of the very worse of all the childhoods. The degree of emphasis is stronger.

("The most horrendous childhood" singular would mean worse than every single childhood ever, which is literally stronger again but in sounding like hyperbole is perhaps actually weakened).

Comment: Thank you, Jon, very clear comparison. But I can hardly understand the very last sentence.

Comment: @Sergey Think about these two usages: "That poor child had the most horrendous childhood. Both his parents died and his foster parents made him do all sorts of manual labor for them and never treated him well." <-- This sounds like a pretty bad childhood. Next: "I had the most horrendous childhood ever. I wasn't allowed to go online after 8:00PM until I was 13." <-- Was this actually the most horrendous childhood?